# when i m trying to make .war file of my WEB-INF folder to deploy in tomcat6, cmd shows error java.io.Filenotfound Exception now., what can i do

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat6, java-io

when i m trying to make .war file of my WEB-INF folder to deploy in tomcat6,

```
 Microsoft Windows (Version 6.2.9200)'
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat6.0\webapps>jar cvf            mywebapp.war */ ..
java.io.FileNotFoundException: mywebapp.war (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:84)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:167)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1147)
```

then  cmd shows error

" java.io.Filenotfound Exception:mywebapp.war(access is denide)"  what can i do.. to make .war file..

Comment: You should have a look at this article : http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2012/03/how-to-fix-javaiofilenotfoundexception.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try starting tomcat with admin priviledges by `"run as administrator"`

or

change the properties to "Apache Software Foundation" and its subfolders from `folder_name>properties>security`

or

install the `tomcat` to any other location than `c:\` drive (OS installation drive)